# Is it possible to nest easylists?

Tags: pdftex, easylist

I would like to have a combined list like this:

> 1. item
>
>    • sub item
>
>    • another sub item
> 2. ...

I have this:

```
\begin{easylist}[enumerate]
    & item
    \begin{easylist}[itemize]
        & sub item
        & another sub item
    \end{easylist}
    & ...
\end{easylist}
```

And the output looks like this:

> 1. item
>
>    • sub item
>
>    • another sub item
>
>    • ...

Now, I know that I'm the one who is doing something wrong, but I can't find a way to achieve the look I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There may be better ways.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[at]{easylist}
\newcommand\bulletize[1]{\hspace{20pt}$\bullet$}
\begin{document}
\begin{easylist}
\ListProperties(CtrCom2=\bulletize)
    @ item
        @@ sub item
        @@ another sub item
    @ ...
\end{easylist}
\end{document}
```

[image]